# IE10 IIS7.5 formatting incorrectly

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, internet-explorer-10

I'm running into a formatting problem that only occurs with IE10 and Win2008 with IIS7.5.  Using the IE10 compatibility modes via the developers toolbar, IE7,8,9,10 all work with Win2003 and IIS6.  It also works with IE7,8,9 and Win2008 with IIS7.5.  However, with IE10 and IIS7.5, the very same code formats the textboxes differently.  (IE10 compatibility mode works correctly)

There are two main problems - a comment text box is not displaying at the proper width (it displays at default width).  Here is the code (all the JS is working properly):

```
       <asp:TextBox runat="server" Height="50px" ID="JustificationTxt" TextMode="MultiLine" 
            onkeyup="AutoExpandTextbox(this)" onfocus="OnFocusJustificationComments(this)" 
            onblur="OnBlurJustificationComments(this)"  Columns="50" Rows="10" Width="98%" 
            Text="<%# VM.commentText %>" />
```

Also, some readonly text boxes are not rendering in the proper color (however the readonly attribute is working):

```
<asp:TextBox BackColor="#eeeeee" ReadOnly="True" ID="ACWPcumTxt" runat="server" Text="<%# VM.ETCGridRow.ACWPcumDisplay%>" />
```

Remember that all of this works in the other configurations.

What am I missing?

Comment: You say Compatibility works correctly, so I assume we can eliminate the server sending an `x-ua-compatible` header then?

Comment: Sorry, i don't know what that means.  Is it something I need to set in the page or on IIS?  This is in my master page:  <!DOCTYPE html>